# Spacing before parenthesis in math mode

Tags: math-mode, spacing, amsmath

Suppose, I have something like

```
\overline{q}_{l m_1}'(i) \overline{q}_{l m_2}'(i) \overline{q}_{l m_3}'(i)
```

Now, this renders to

[image: LaTeX rendering of code above]

which looks rather unpleasant. How can I reduce the spaces in front of the opening parentheses? The q's are functions of i, hence there should be no space at all.

I am using amsmath and mtpro2 for Times font in math mode, but the problem occurs regardless of these settings.

Many thanks in advance,
Lennex

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! Standard commands would be `\!` or `\mkern-3mu` or whatever number of `mu` (math units) you need.

Comment: I'd use `\bar` instead of `\overline`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may set small spaces (1/6 of a quad) manually: negative `\!` and positive `\,`:

```
\overline{q}_{l m_1}'\!(i)\,\overline{q}_{l m_2}'\!(i)\,\overline{q}_{l m_3}'\!(i)
```